# Printing multiple pages with printThis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 50 line table within a div (divbody below) that I need to print.  When using printThis.js, I can only print one page.  This is my code to print:

```
<script defer src='printThis.js'></script>
<script defer>
  $('#printButton').click (function() {
   var divBodyElement = $('#divbody').clone(true);
   var divBodyElementFind = divBodyElement.find();                                                                    divBodyElementFind.addBack(divBodyElement);
                                                              divBodyElementFindWithAddBackScrollHidden =                         divBodyElementFindWithAddBack.css('overflow','hidden');
                                            $(divBodyElementFindWithAddBackScrollHidden).printThis();
  return true;
```

});

This works except only one page prints and its cut off right where the scroll bar ends.  Any thoughts on how to fix?

I can only print one page.

---

Ok, to answer my own question, I just needed the children, not the parent.  With the following, printThis now prints multiple pages more or less correctly.

```
var divBodyElement = $('#divbody').clone(true);
var divBodyElementChildren = divBodyElement.children();
$(divBodyElementChildren).printThis();
```

Comment: Then add that to answer the question. You can even accept for yourself. Adding to the question as you've done may not be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: You can answer (and accept it) your own question so people looking for the answer can find it quicker.